# MediaPlayer : Audio won't stream from beginning

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I'm using `MediaPlayer` in android to stream a few audio files that are added via a `ListView`. The audio is played when the item is clicked from the `ListView`.

The streams are quite long (35minutes+) and if the user exits the application before the stream ends. Then when the item is selected again from the `ListView` after launching, the stream is resumed from the same place where it was left off, whereas, I want it to start from the beginning whenever the item is selected from the `ListView`.

Here's the code :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    musicService.player.reset();
    musicService.player.release();
    musicService.player = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        musicService.player.setDataSource(skURL[position]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    musicService.player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    musicService.player.prepareAsync();
    musicService.player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    musicService.playSK();
}

//In the MusicService.java

public void playSK(){
    player.start();
}
```

I tried setting the seek position to 0 in the `playSK()` method thinking that it would solve the problem like

```
public void playSK(){
    player.seekTo(0);
    player.start();
}
```

and it partially did. When the first item of the `ListView` is selected then the stream always starts from the beginning, but clicking any other item gives the following error :

```
MediaPlayer : error (-2147483648, 0)
MediaPlayer : start called in state 0
MediaPlayer : error (-38, 0)
MediaPlayer : Error (-2147483648, 0)
MediaPlayer : Error (-38, 0)
```

Update :

So I decided to dig into why there was a problem caused when trying to seek to the beginning of the track and i found out that the mediaplayer was unable to get the duration due to a protocol exception.

```
10-01 17:35:06.065 10031-10031/project D/LOG: data source set
10-01 17:35:06.065 10031-10031/project D/LOG: preparing media player
10-01 17:35:06.067 10031-10066/project D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 6.0.1)
10-01 17:35:06.070 10031-10031/project D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
10-01 17:35:06.073 10031-10031/porject D/LOG: media player prepared
10-01 17:35:06.074 10031-10066/project D/MediaHTTPConnection: proxy null port 0
10-01 17:35:06.171 10031-10066/project W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 12648448 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
10-01 17:43:43.352 21618-21618/project D/LOG: seeking to start
10-01 17:43:43.352 21618-21618/project W/MediaPlayer: Stream has no duration and is therefore not seekable.
```

How do I handle this exception and resolve the problem?

Comment: focus on the various states of the MP object. IMO if you have the right track loaded and the player in correct state, you should have NP with a call to seek()

Comment: Updated : how do I deal with the ProtocolException?

Comment: if u r not familiar with ffmpeg,  try uploading the media to youtube, then download from youtube and re-try your seek on the downloaded version.. it may be fine then because utube remux'd it with an Atom

Comment: This is an mp3 file, are you sure remux is relevant?

Comment: u may want to check into the mp3 spec - looking for the header making it seekable....

Comment: Reuploading the file fixed the issue. Dunno what was wrong...

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Seek is not possible, the audio does play though.

Answer (score 0):

try making media player object to null after musicService.player.release();

```
musicService.player = null;
```

me too faced this issue the only workaround that works for me is making it null. If you still faced any issue let me know

Comment: Done that, didn't help.

Comment: in onPrepared method you should use that object given inside parameters

Comment: That does not help either. Is it possible that somehow the device caches the duration that the song has reached in the URL and then simply passes that cached duration to the `player.setDataSource` method? because when i repeatedly press the item, it skips forward by 3-4 seconds and then sometimes randomly starts from the beginning. So it is likely skipping because it has buffered and stored data in some temporary file and when it runs out of buffered data it goes to the start of the track....